# In how many ways are we able to permute a set $[n]$ such that for each $2\le k\le n$: $\sigma(k) \ne k-1$

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

In how many ways are we able to permute a set $[n]$ such that for each $2\le k\le n$:

$$\sigma(k) \ne k-1$$

---

This is like the partial derangement,however $1$ is not fixed,clearly $1$ has $n$ places which can be mapped to ,but I could't find a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of those is all permutations minus the ones in which this happens. Meaning
$$\left | S_n\setminus \bigcup _{i=2}^nA_i\right |,$$ where $$A_i = \{ \sigma \in S_n:\sigma(i)=i-1 \},$$ Notice that 
$|A_i|=(n-1)!$ because we are just forcing one variable to be settle. Same happens for $|A_i\cap A_j|=(n-2)!$ by the same reasoning and so, in genera, $$\left |\bigcap _{i\in I} A_i\right |=(n-|I|)!.$$
The inclusion-exclusion principle tells you that
$$|\bigcup _{i=2}^nA_i|=\sum _{k = 1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\sum _{\substack{I\subseteq \{2,3,\cdots ,n\}\\|I|=k}}\left |\bigcap _{i\in I} A_i\right |=\sum _{k = 1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\sum _{\substack{I\subseteq \{2,3,\cdots ,n\}\\|I|=k}}(n-|I|)!=\sum _{k = 1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}(n-k)!\sum _{\substack{I\subseteq \{2,3,\cdots ,n\}\\|I|=k}}1=\sum _{k = 1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}(n-k)!\binom{n-1}{k}$$
and so your formula looks like
$$n!+\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}(n-i)!=\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}(n-i)!$$

Looking up the numbers, they are [here](https://oeis.org/A000255)

Comment: Which is $nD_{n-1}+\left(n-1\right)D_{n-2}$,can you just explain about the inclusion-exclusion part?thanks

Comment: @user715522 I edited it. You are welcome.

Comment: @ Phicar,Since it seems that you are familiar with these kind of question,then can you please [look](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674724/a-special-case-of-double-derangement-with-k-1-ne-sigmak-ne-k?noredirect=1#comment7558374_3674724) at this post?